# Could someone provide an example of an automorphism?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, symmetry, automorphism-group

I have been trying to find an exampke fo an automorphism of $ℚ$.

I have tried with some simple equations, such as

$$a + n$$

$$n*a$$

$$a^n$$

(being $a$ an element in $ℚ$ and $n$ a constant)

None of the latter examples form an automorphism. There is clearly the identity, but that is kind of trivial.

So I was wondering, could someone provide an example of an automorphism of $ℚ$ besides the identity?

---

Any help/thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: Automorphism as a field?  But any automorphism of a field fixes the smallest subfield containing $1$, which in this case is all of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34217/field-automorphisms-of-mathbbq-shouldnt-there-be-only-one).

Comment: If you are viewing $\mathbb{Q}$ as a group (with a single operation, rather than as a field with two compatible operations) then the "inversion" map is an automorphism. That is, if you are thinking of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ the the map $x\mapsto -x$ is an automorphism, while if you are thinking of $(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}, \ast)$ then $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an automorphism.